# Adding a Ribbon Checkbox that is checked by default? (Pwp add in - C# and Xml)

Tags: c#, xml, checkbox, powerpoint, ribbon

XML code:

```
<checkBox 
           id="Fill"
           label="F"
           getPressed="CheckedByDefault"
/>
```

C# code:

```
public void CheckedByDefault(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            RibbonCheckBox ch =  control;
            ch.Checked = true;
         }
```

I am not able to declare the RibbonCheckbox in this way and, therefore, not able to access and modify its "Checked" property.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

C# code:

```
public void CheckedByDefault(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: How can a void function return a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I was looking for a good example of how to do this and was unable to find a good example. I finally figured it out and thought I'd post to help someone else in the future.

You could set the value in the XML for the checkbox control as follows-

```
enabled="true"
```

Another option is to set the checkbox dynamically by setting a property to true or false to toggle it on or off as follows-

```
public static string YourPropertyValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

 public bool CheckedByDefault(IRibbonControl ribbon)
    {
        //Check Checkbox
        if (YourPropertyValue == true)
        {
            return true;
        }

        //Uncheck Checkbox
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```